# How to Pass current date if there is null value in the field?

Tags: sql-server

FORMAT(a.[Installation Date], 'G') as Installed,

Here i am passing the date values from installed date to Installed.
I am looking for a syntax to check if the field has null value, then current date needs to be passed to installed.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Give this a try FORMAT(IsNull((a.[Installation Date],GetDate()), 'G')

Comment: Thanks for your reply John,

Comment: Tried with your suggestion, getting error using this

Comment: Does [Installation Date]  have a datatype of Datetime or is it a string?

Comment: it is of a "datetime" datatype

Comment: What error ?  What version of SQL Server ?  Select @@version

Comment: See answer below for a bit more

Comment: Error: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 73
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.      SQL Server name and Version: SQL Server Management Studio 17.8.1

Comment: Had an extra ( after IsNull(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IsNull()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table ([Installation Date] datetime)
Insert into @YourTable values
('2018-05-22 12:18:22')
,(null)

Select FORMAT(IsNull(a.[Installation Date],GetDate()), 'G') 
 From @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
5/22/2018 12:18:22 PM
9/4/2018 12:14:51 PM
```